# Функция для проверки символа Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно написать функцию которая, для строки, переданной в качестве аргумента, проверяет для каждого предложения, является ли его последним символом "!", "?" или точка и сообщает, какое это предложение - восклицательное, вопросительное или повествовательное.

Comment: И что именно у Вас не получается? Где примеры Ваших попыток?

Comment: Я просто не успеваю, у меня еще несколько заданий, на пересдаче сижу, грозят отчислением. Прошу Вас помочь, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const mySentence = "Как дела?";

function checkSentence(val) {
  const last = val.trim()[val.length - 1];
  
  if (last == "?") console.log("Вопросительное");
  else if (last == "!") console.log("Восклицательное");
  else if (last == ".") console.log("Повествовательное.");
}

checkSentence(mySentence);
```

Comment: а если будет строка вида "Hello world! " ?

Comment: val.trim(), я забыл.

Comment: а если "hello world" ?

Comment: В условии ничего про это нет, написано либо восклицательное, либо...

Answer (score 0):

```
const check = string => {
    string = string.trim();
    switch (string[string.length - 1]) {
        case '.': return 'повествовательное';
        case '!': return 'восклицательное';
        case '?': return 'вопросительное';

        default: return null
    }

}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!